# Java JSF DataTable definition

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to create a datatable using JSF primefaces. I know there is a tag called datatable but am really unclear on how to use it. As in I can't picture its relationship with the bean. My table should be ID, Status, Details. Any idea how to do this or where to go for it?
oh forgot to add that the number of rows will depend on returned from resultset from database.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert your result set into the `List` of entity (for example `List<Book>` ) and then set it as Bean 's property,

and use following code in XHTML

```
 <p:dataTable id="books" value="#{yourBean.books}" var="book">  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Title" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" />  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column>  
        <f:facet name="header">  
            <h:outputText value="Author" />  
        </f:facet>  
        <h:outputText value="#{book.author}" />  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>
```

---

**Book POJO**

```
public class Book{
  private String author;
  private String title; 
  //accessors + constructors 
}
```

---

**Managed Bean**

```
@ManagedBean
public class YourBean{
  private List<Book> books;
  //accesors + constructors 
}
```

---

**See Also**

- [Showcase - primefaces data table](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/pprDataTable.jsf)

Comment: yourBean.books is what? a variable holding what? any glimpse into java code into the bean? sorry this is the first time to test datatable :( I also need to make some of the fields clickable like ID details for example :/

Comment: actually the code there is useful. what about clicking the field to go to another page to view request?

Comment: ok i changed many things to try and make this work smoothly. Just stuck when I do the table where it says book.title and book.author. I have now created a class ie RequestClass where i store the details such as ID, details and status of request. then i have a method which returns a list with all request objects, one for each request. How can I access it the way it is mentioned here?? :(

Comment: @sys_debug can you elaborate the structure in the question please

Comment: Jigar could u help me with URL parameter issue?

Comment: I am trying to pass parameter and ive been using managedProperty. The only thing I need to post again from that page, but the id variable holding the value is null. I heard that if i intend to post again, then I should use f:param. been trying but no luck. the code below is working but only with managedproperty. how can I add f:param correctly?

Comment: can you please open new post for new question

Answer (score 0):

the answer I needed after Jigar helped me greatly is:

```
               <p:dataTable style="width:50px;" id="requestList" value="#
                {requestBean.requestsList}" var="requestClass">  
                <p:column>  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="ID" />  
                    </f:facet> 
                     <a href="review.xhtml?id=#{requestClass.requestID}">
                        <h:outputText value="#{requestClass.requestID}" />  
                     </a>

                </p:column>  

                <p:column>  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Status" />  
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{requestClass.requestStatus}" />  
                </p:column>  

                  <p:column>  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Details" />  
                    </f:facet>  
                      <h:outputText value="#{requestClass.requestTitle}" />  
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
```